# @react-pdf/renderer PDF View takes extremely long to render when there are many images

Tags: reactjs, renderer, react-pdf

I have around 20 images in the generated PDF and it is taking around 20 seconds just to render the PDF. Does any using @react-pdf/renderer have a similar issue and if so, how did you go about solving it?

This is the link to the the documentation of the react pdf library: https://react-pdf.org/